# Vue ошибки методов

Tags: vue.js

Есть Vue компонент, в нем есть два метода earnForPlan() и earnForGiveout(), в них есть условия, но эти условия не работают. В чем может быть проблема?

```
<template>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inp_info">
            <label for="plan">Введите план:</label>
            <input id="plan" v-model="newPlan" type="text">
            <label for="salary">Введите оклад:</label>
            <input id="salary" v-model="newSalary" type="text">
        </div>
  <div class="giveout">
            <label for="giveout-inp">Вводи сумму выдачи и жми на кнопку:</label>
            <input id="giveout-inp" v-model="newItem" type="text">
            <button v-on:click="addNumbers"  class="giveout_sum" id="giveout-sum">Я все сложу</button>
            <div class="giveout-sumValue">{{ sum() }}</div>   
        </div>
        <div class="myMoney">
          <h1>Я получу</h1>
          <div class="forPlan">За план: {{ earnForPlan() }}</div>
          <div class="forGiveout">За выдачи: {{ earnForGiveout() }}</div>
        </div>
        <sumIns></sumIns>
        </div> 
</template>

<script>
import sumIns from './sumIns.vue';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
        newItem:'',
        numbers: [],
        newPlan:'',
        newSalary:'',
    }
      },
    methods: {
        addNumbers() {
            let num = +this.newItem;
            this.numbers.push(num);
            this.newItem = '';
        },
        sum() {
            let sum = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < this.numbers.length; i++ ) {
                sum += this.numbers[i];  
            }
            return sum;
        },
        earnForPlan() {
          let a = this.sum();
          let percent = ((a / this.newPlan) * 100).toFixed(0);
          if (percent >= 76 || percent <= 99) {
            return (4 * (a / this.newPlan - 0.75) * 0.5 * +this.newSalary).toFixed(1)
          } else if (percent == 100) {
           return (+this.newSalary / 2)
          } else if (percent > 100 || percent < 125) {
            return ((2 * (a / this.newPlan) - 1) * 0.5 * +this.newSalary).toFixed(1)
          } else if (percent >= 125) {
            return (+this.newSalary*1.5/2)
          } else {
            return ('Плохо работаешь дружок!')
          }
        },
        earnForGiveout() {
          let b = this.sum();
          console.log(b);
          if (b >= 3000000 || b < 6000000) {
            return '5000';
          } else if (b >= 6000000 || b < 9000000) {
            return '10000';
          } else if (b >= 9000000 || b < 12000000) {
            return '15000';
          } else if (b >= 12000000) {
            return '20000';
          } else {
            return ('Очень хреновый месяц');
          }
        }
    },
    components: {
        sumIns: sumIns
}
}
</script>
```

[image: Вот что выводит console.log(и)]

Comment: ну так и что `console.log(b)` вывел?

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, Выводит сумму после нажатия на кнопку, прикрепил скрин в вопрос.
Еще такой интересный момент в методе earnForPlan() первые два условия считаются правильно, но после 100% идет билиберда какая-то.

Comment: А теперь попробуй установи `window.console.log(percent)` на третьей строке в методе `earnForPlan`. Как там вообще число можно получить? Может и не в этом ошибка, не хочу разбираться в логике, но там будет как минимум строка после `toFixed`

Comment: ...PS А когда нет значения в `this.newPlan` там будет вообще `NaN`

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, действительно после toFixed была строка.

Comment: Дело тут не в `Vue` и методах, а в элементарном неверном написании всего того, что внутри `earnForPlan`. Причем почти на каждой стоке - приведи все к числам.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg теперь если 125% то считает правильно, но есть одно но, если идет выше 125%, то сумма всегда должна быть 17250, но она растет с каждым новым суммированием

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg да там конечно был косяк с типами данных, но даже взять второй метод, мы там ничего не считаем, просто следим за суммой. Однако он и вовсе не работает.